# Why can't I use the async library from pub.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, dependencies, dart-pub

Um.. yeah... so I wanted to use a Timer in a flutter app, and realized I needed to import the async library in order to do so.

So, per the installation instructions on pub.dev, I added the dependency to pubspec.yaml:

```
async: ^2.5.0
```

But when I run pub-get, the following text shows up in the messages tab:

> Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on async
> 2.5.0-nullsafety.1 and flutter_app depends on async ^2.5.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden. So, because flutter_app depends on
> flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed. pub get failed (1;
> So, because flutter_app depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version
> solving failed.)

I'm trying to decipher this.  Can you decipher this complex boolean algebraic word problem?

Comment: `Timer` is from `dart:async` from the Dart SDK itself, not from `package:async`.  They are separate.

Comment: As for your error, your app requires a slightly newer version of `package:async` than allowed by `flutter_test` from Flutter.  You either could update your version of Flutter (the current version should depend on `async: 2.5.0` instead of `2.5.0-nullsafety.1`) or adjust your app's requirement to `async: ^2.5.0-nullsafety.1`.